# Run custom model's Intermediate Representation (IR), OpenVino

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, openvino

I converted my custom pytorch model into Intermediate Representation (IR), to run it in OpenVino. However, I can't find any (simple) tutorial/guide to do that. I know OpenVino has it's own build-in files to run some famous models ([link](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/tree/master/inference-engine/samples)). But, is there any simple guide to run IR in OpenVino?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the link below for the step-by-step guide on integration steps:

https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html#integration_steps

Comment: Thanks, but is there any python guide?

Comment: This step-by-step guide on integration steps only available in C++. However, you can refer to the python samples.https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/tree/master/inference-engine/ie_bridges/python/sample